# React Native: change bottom android notch color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have been stuck with this issue for a few days, I want to change the color of the bottom notch on android phones to red, to no success...

Notice the highlighted bottom
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxaxH.jpg

I use react native navigation V6

Things I tried:

**1)** Changing the background color of tab navigator

```
tabBarStyle: [
    { 
        width:'100%',height:60,backgroundColor:'transparent' },
```

**2)** changing default theme of NavigationContainer

```
const MyTheme = {
        ...DefaultTheme,
        colors: {
          ...DefaultTheme.colors,
          background: 'red',
          primary: 'red',
        },
      };

<NavigationContainer theme={DefaultTheme}>
            <ROOTSTACK1></ROOTSTACK1>
        </NavigationContainer>
```

**3)** Changing backgroundColor of rootstack

```
<RootStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: true, navigationBarColor:'red' }}>
```

None of this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixing it making my screen like this:

```js
<View style={{flex: 1, background: '#FFF'}}>
  <StatusBar backgroundColor="#FFF" barStyle="dark-content" />
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  {...components}
  </SafeAreaView>
</View>
```

Comment: sadly did not work.

Comment: @gabogabans try this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarstyle

Comment: Already tried tabBarStyle

Comment: and this `tabBarStyle: { position: 'absolute' }`